# Qual a diferença entre factory, service ou controller em Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Seguinte, na prática, qual a diferença e como se faz serviço com .service, .factory e controller?

service.js

```
angular.module('app.services', [])

.factory('BlankFactory', [function(){

}])

.service('BlankService', [function(){

}]);
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('servicoControler', function($scope) {

})
```

Vi esse vídeo, mas não entendi a diferença:
[Angular Factory vs Service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLzNCkPn3ao)

Comment: Vê se a resposta dessa pergunta te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory

Comment: factory retonar valores de funções e service não retorna nada, só o argumento passado no parâmetro da function, correto?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O `controller` seria o mediador **principal** de seu *model* e sua *view*. Nele você faria as manipulações necessárias para a interação com os serviços de sua aplicação. Quando digo serviços, não me refiro estritamente ao `service`, mas também ao `.factory`, ao `.provider`, ao `.config` e ao `.value`.

#### Factory

O nome **factory** faz referência a `Factory Function`, que são aquelas funções que retornam um objeto. Por exemplo:

```
var pessoa = function(nome, idade) {
  return {
    nome: nome,
    idade: idade
  }
}
var maria = pessoa("Maria", 23);
maria.idade; // 23
```

É nessa estrutura que a **factory** trabalha. Nela você retorna um objeto reusável (principal questão dos services - reusabilidade) no *controller*, a partir do parâmetro passado. Por exemplo:

```
.factory('usersAPI', [function($http){
     var _getUsers = function(){
         return $http.get('/users');
     };
     return{
        getUsers: _getUsers
     }
}])
```

#### Service

Já o **service** trabalha na estrutura de uma `Constructor Function`:

```
var Pessoa = function(nome, idade) {
  this.nome = nome;
  this.idade = idade;
}
var maria = new Pessoa("Maria", 23);
maria.idade; // 23
```

Estas também funcionam como um objeto, mas não o retornam. Trabalham com o uso do `this`. Exemplo que faz a mesma coisa do exemplo com o *factory*:

```
.service('usersAPI', function($http) {
  this.getUsers = function() {
    return $http.get('/users');
  };
})
```

No *controller* para chamar um desses serviços bastaria adicionar seu script e acrescentar a dependência com seu nome:

```
.controller('servicoControler', function($scope, usersAPI) {
    usersAPI.getUsers(); // retorna o get
})
```

No exemplo acima, esse mesmo código funcionaria para os dois casos já ditos. Como os dois, **no exemplo**, possuem o mesmo nome, seria aconselhável usar apenas um serviço.

É tudo uma questão de estruturação, design e principalmente reusabilidade do código.

Comment: Ótima resposta, Samir!

Comment: Neste caso, então o Factory seria recomendado por exemplo para armazenar os dados do usuário logado na plataforma, sem precisar executar um http request cada vez que preciso dos dados dele?